# More efficient way to initiate 100 buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, performance

I have a class that is going to need ~100 buttons.  I know I can code it like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="65dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollviewborder"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b11"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b12"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b13"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b14"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b16"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b17"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b18"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b19"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/b20"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But that does not seem very performance efficient and I know if I keep doing that it will soon flag a warning that I have too many lines of code.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?  XML or in Java will do, it doesn't matter which way.

**EDIT**

I have caused an uproar about having 100 buttons in my design.  Let me explain why.

Anyone here play the Android/Apple app Candy Crush Saga? You know how they have 400+ levels to play that you unlock one at a time? That is similar to what I am doing so that is why I need so many buttons.

After that explanation, if I still am doing this wrong, please let me know as I am still a beginner Android programmer.

Comment: Well... Why do you need so many buttons? If they all do something similar, they could be created and added using a loop.

Comment: You could try to define a single Button in a layout and <include> it when needed though a ListView could be better.

Comment: Instead of that LinearLayout and so many buttons inside, why don't use a ListView instead?

Comment: 100 buttons! too much rethink your design

Comment: I was going to suggest the loop, you would have your button section in the XML and then another buttonNum that would feed into the loop, so it could be easily modified for different pages / screens

Comment: There's almost certainly a better way to do this. 100 Buttons is waay too many.

Comment: In swing one would use a JTable with a cell renderer reusing the same JButton for all 100 buttons. Do not know about android.

Comment: Anyone here play the Android/Apple app `Candy Crush Saga`?  You know how they have 400+ levels to play that you unlock one at a time?  That is similar to what I am doing so that is why I need so many buttons.  From a couple of the comments above, `ListView` seems like a good route?  Yes?

Comment: use ListView instead ...

Comment: +1 for an interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this correctly, use a two-step process. The first thing to note is that each of your buttons has a unique ID. It is best practice to declare all your ID's in `XML`, to ensure uniqueness. So step one is to setup your ids xml file (you can ignore this if you actually don't care about the id).

Under the `res/values` directory, create the file *ids.xml*, with the following contents:

```
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="b1" />
    <item type="id" name="b2" />
    <item type="id" name="b3" />
    <item type="id" name="b4" />
    <item type="id" name="b5" />
    <item type="id" name="b6" />
    <item type="id" name="b7" />
    <item type="id" name="b8" />
    <item type="id" name="b9" />
    <item type="id" name="b10" />
    <item type="id" name="b11" />
    <item type="id" name="b12" />
    <item type="id" name="b13" />
    <item type="id" name="b14" />
    <item type="id" name="b15" />
    <item type="id" name="b16" />
    <item type="id" name="b17" />
    <item type="id" name="b18" />
    <item type="id" name="b19" />
    <item type="id" name="b20" />
    <item type="id" name="b21" />
    <item type="id" name="b22" />
    <item type="id" name="b23" />
    <item type="id" name="b24" />
    <item type="id" name="b25" />
    <item type="id" name="b26" />
    <item type="id" name="b27" />
    <item type="id" name="b28" />
    <item type="id" name="b29" />
    <item type="id" name="b30" />
    <item type="id" name="b31" />
    <item type="id" name="b32" />
    <item type="id" name="b33" />
    <item type="id" name="b34" />
    <item type="id" name="b35" />
    <item type="id" name="b36" />
    <item type="id" name="b37" />
    <item type="id" name="b38" />
    <item type="id" name="b39" />
    <item type="id" name="b40" />
    <item type="id" name="b41" />
    <item type="id" name="b42" />
    <item type="id" name="b43" />
    <item type="id" name="b44" />
    <item type="id" name="b45" />
    <item type="id" name="b46" />
    <item type="id" name="b47" />
    <item type="id" name="b48" />
    <item type="id" name="b49" />
    <item type="id" name="b50" />
    <item type="id" name="b51" />
    <item type="id" name="b52" />
    <item type="id" name="b53" />
    <item type="id" name="b54" />
    <item type="id" name="b55" />
    <item type="id" name="b56" />
    <item type="id" name="b57" />
    <item type="id" name="b58" />
    <item type="id" name="b59" />
    <item type="id" name="b60" />
    <item type="id" name="b61" />
    <item type="id" name="b62" />
    <item type="id" name="b63" />
    <item type="id" name="b64" />
    <item type="id" name="b65" />
    <item type="id" name="b66" />
    <item type="id" name="b67" />
    <item type="id" name="b68" />
    <item type="id" name="b69" />
    <item type="id" name="b70" />
    <item type="id" name="b71" />
    <item type="id" name="b72" />
    <item type="id" name="b73" />
    <item type="id" name="b74" />
    <item type="id" name="b75" />
    <item type="id" name="b76" />
    <item type="id" name="b77" />
    <item type="id" name="b78" />
    <item type="id" name="b79" />
    <item type="id" name="b80" />
    <item type="id" name="b81" />
    <item type="id" name="b82" />
    <item type="id" name="b83" />
    <item type="id" name="b84" />
    <item type="id" name="b85" />
    <item type="id" name="b86" />
    <item type="id" name="b87" />
    <item type="id" name="b88" />
    <item type="id" name="b89" />
    <item type="id" name="b90" />
    <item type="id" name="b91" />
    <item type="id" name="b92" />
    <item type="id" name="b93" />
    <item type="id" name="b94" />
    <item type="id" name="b95" />
    <item type="id" name="b96" />
    <item type="id" name="b97" />
    <item type="id" name="b98" />
    <item type="id" name="b99" />
    <item type="id" name="b100" />
</resources>
```

Next, create your buttons in code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button(this);
    int _id = getResources().getIdentifier("b" + (i+1), "id", this.getPackageName());
    button.setTag(_id);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0);
    params.weight = 1;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    button.setLayoutParams(params);
    button.setTextSize(18);
    myLinearLayout.addView(button);//myLinearLayout is your parent LinearLayout.
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  This is what I was hoping was out there as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    Button button = (Button) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.button_view, null);
    // Do stuff to your button, add onClickListeners, etc.
    rootView.addView(button);
}
```

Where `rootView` is a `LinearLayout` or similar that you have instantiated earlier.

and `res/layout/button_view.xml` is something like:

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Please pay attention http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need that many buttons there's nothing you can do about it. If you want to keep your code short, you can have a loop in your Java code, but I personally prefer the XML version because then you see your layout right in your IDE.

The only thing I think is worth doing is creating a new style for those buttons. They all have 18sp text size and you might want to add some other attributes later.

Also, remove layout_gravity="center" and layout_weight=1, they have no effect in your case.

And don't use fill_parent, use match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

It's way more proper to do it in java.

```
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_liner_layout); // Get the liner layout

  for (i=0; i <= 100; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button(this); // Create a button

     btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // setting the gravity

     btn.setText("button number " + i); //setting the text

     LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1); // Creating a LayoutParams : first args is the width, seconds the height and the last one the weight.

     lay.addView(btn, layout); // Adding the button to the linear layout
}
```